# Best way to get List[String] or Future[List[String]] from List[Future[List[String]]] Scala

Tags: scala, future

I have a flow that returns `List[Future[List[String]]]` and I want to convert it to `List[String]` .
Here's what I am doing currently to achieve it -

```
val functionReturnedValue: List[Future[List[String]]] = functionThatReturnsListOfFutureList()

val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[String]

functionReturnedValue.map{futureList =>
      val list = Await.result(futureList, Duration(10, "seconds"))
      list.map(string => listBuffer += string)
    }

listBuffer.toList
```

Waiting inside loop is not good, also need to avoid use of ListBuffer.

Or, if it is possible to get `Future[List[String]]` from `List[Future[List[String]]]`

Could someone please help with this?

Comment: Try to get a value "out" of a `Future` (or "out" of an `Option` etc) is a bad idea. Any result that depends on processing an asynchronous/potentially failed input must be kept inside the `Future` context. In rare case `Await.result` can be used (as `var` can be used in some very specific cases), but you should really wonder how to work with, rather than how to get out from.

Comment: That function that returns a `List[Future]` should be fixed, probably using `Future.traverse` rather than `List.map`

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to get a value from an asynchronus context to the synchronus context wihtout blocking the sysnchronus context to wait for the asynchronus context.

But, yes you can delay that blocking as much as you can do get better results.

```scala
val listFutureList: List[Future[List[String]]] = ???

val listListFuture: Future[List[List[String]]] = Future.sequence(listFutureList)

val listFuture: Future[List[String]] = listListFuture.map(_.flatten)

val list: List[String] = Await.result(listFuture, Duration.Inf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Await.result invokes a blocking operation, which you should avoid if you can.

Just as a side note, in your code you are using `.map` but as you are only interested in the (mutable) ListBuffer you can just use `foreach` which has Unit as a return type.

Instead of mapping and adding item per item, you can use `.appendAll`

```
functionReturnedValue.foreach(fl => 
  listBuffer.appendAll(Await.result(fl, Duration(10, "seconds")))
)
```

As you don't want to use ListBuffer, another way could be using `.sequence` is with a for comprehension and then `.flatten`

```
val fls: Future[List[String]] = for (
  lls <- Future.sequence(functionReturnedValue)
) yield lls.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform `List[Future[In]]` to `Future[List[In]]` **safetly** as follows:

```scala
    def aggregateSafeSequence[In](futures: List[Future[In]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[In]] = {
      val futureTries = futures.map(_.map(Success(_)).recover { case NonFatal(ex) => Failure(ex)})
      Future.sequence(futureTries).map {
        _.foldRight(List[In]()) {
          case (curr, acc) =>
            curr match {
              case Success(res) => res :: acc
              case Failure(ex) => 
                println("Failure occurred", ex)
                acc
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Then you can use `Await.result` In order to wait if you like but it's not recommended and you should avoid it if possible.

Note that in general `Future.sequence`, if one the futures fails all the futures will fail together, so i went to a little different approach.

You can use the same way from `List[Future[List[String]]]` and etc.